# OLEDB, ODBC, Ntext and Nvarchar(max)

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I understand that Microsoft decided back in 2011 to deprecate OLE DB and that no new drivers or maintenance would occur beyond SQL Native Client V11. In future you should use ODBC based drivers - http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2011/09/04/rip-ole-db.aspx

The latest ODBC driver being 'Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' release on 25th July 2016 - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420

ODBC drivers from Native Client V9,10,11 and the Microsoft ODBC Driver SQL Server V11 and 13 all work in Classic ASP code interacting with SQL server (I am using SQL 2012) except for one problem - nText and Nvarchar(max).

They just return blank - I have seen solutions saying you should read into a local variable first rather than addressing the recordset directly e.g. varStr=rs("LargeText"), but that does not work for me. And there is other mentions of using get chunk etc.

But I am quite happily using Native Client V9 (Provider=SQLNCLI) which works perfectly with these data types.

So, my questions are:

Is there anyway to get ODBC drivers working with nText/Nvarchar(max) datatypes?

Is there any benefit to using ODBC over OLEDB?

Do I have to upgade to ODBC at some stage in order to connect to SQL server in future i.e. SQL 2014/2016?

In other words, can I just carry on using OLEDB going forward?

---

OK, Lankymart - I would use something like this:

```
Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Open "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=*Yourserver*;Database=*YourDatabase*;User ID=*YourUserid*;Password=*YourPassword*;"   
'oConn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=*YourServer*; Database=*YourDatabase*;User ID=*YourUserID*;Password=*YourPassword*;" 
set view=oConn.Execute("SELECT [PText] FROM [TextTest]")
ttext=view("PText")
response.write(ttext)
view.Close
set view = Nothing
oConn.Close
set oConn = Nothing
```

Where [PText] is an NVARCHAR(Max) field in SQL. This does not work using the native client ODBC ({SQL Server Native Client 11.0}) but will work using OLE DB (SQLNCLI11).

Comment: Even with SQL 2014/2016 or future SQL releases?

Comment: You are probably using the [wrong connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-odbc-driver/) if Native Client via ODBC isn't working for you.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131267(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: I thought the Native Client releases ended with SQL Native Client 11 (SQL 2012 release) which contained both OLE DB and ODBC releases and the latest driver available is 'Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' which is ODBC only.

Comment: Have you tried using `Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server`? I can confirm that I also cannot access `nvarchar(max)` using `{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}`. [Sounds like it maybe a known issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/467300/problem-with-varchar-max-via-sql-native-client) and probably best to carry on using `SQLNCLI11` for now.

Comment: Interestingly the `ttext` value is not empty and `TypeName(ttext)` returns `String`. I've managed to step through to output the `Hex()` like  so `hx = Right("00" & UCase(Hex(AscB(MidB(str, i, 1)))), 2)` then building up a list of hex values, there is certainly something there but what I don't know. You can also use `Len(ttext)` and `LenB(ttext)` to see the length of the contained value in string size and storage size.

Comment: Yes, I have tried MS ODBC Driver 13 with same result. I had not come across that article - seems it's been a bugbear for a number of people for sometime! Interesting that you get something with the hex values. Do you think you can disambiguate it?

Comment: From what I can gather it almost looks as though the driver is pulling back the wrong LOB I'm getting past values returned mixed with gibberish but not the value I've set in the table. It definitely points to something not right with the interaction between the ODBC driver and ADODB. The size being pulled is correct but the data contained within seems to be pointing to a previous location as it contains phrases I'd written into the column using a [Lorem Ipsum Generator](http://www.lipsum.com/) then overwrote with smaller text to test.

Comment: Here is a sample of what's contained `is ï¿½tes accessing larg fri:obortis odio fermentum ut` the weird bit here is I've written `demonstrate accessing large text data types` into the column previously but you can quite clearly see in the return text extract `accessing larg` mixed with lorem lpsum text from another previous edit of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use `driver={SQL Server};...`? It works for me but with a issue. You need to read into a local variable because if you tried to use it again it will return null.

See the code below:

```
Print rs!varcharmaxVariable 'Returns ok
Print rs!varcharmaxVariable 'Returns null
...
```

Comment: According to connection strings that would be the pre-native client driver for SQL Server 2000 and 7.0: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2000/. Looks like you are using this in a Visual Basic app? Which provider ODBC pack are you using? Surprisingly, using that driver string does run in an ASP app using SQL 2012 as backend with native clients V9,10 and 11 installed. But no different to the other ODBC drivers in regards to trying to access nvarchar(max) fields.

Comment: But I don't need to install any SQL client since it will use the Windows ODBC driver in odbc32.dll.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the field size from varchar(MAX) to a set size. If you cannot change the size in the database, you can cast your select statement and it will work with ODBC Driver 13.